# Failure to extract data from world weather online API in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to extract historical data of 10 years from world weather online Api by saving it in the form of CSV, but in the middle of execution, it stopped after June 2017.
Are there any issues from WWO side or from my side, since I was able to extract data successfully till yesterday.

[This is the portion I've tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQFI9.png)

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuF7J.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The website sends back a response which includes a JSON document, and that document does not include the `weather` key. I would suggest looking at that JSON document - it may contain an error message that would explain what is going wrong.